# dereference make variables inline

Tags: makefile, gnu

i have a piece of tcl code that evaluates a set of variables. the values of these variables then need to be passed as arguments to the next line in the recipe

```
enter code here

MY_ENV_VAR?=45  
foo:ARG1?=test  
foo:OUTFILE:=./testFile  
foo:  
$(shell ./evalVars.tcl -arg1 $(ARG1) -outFile $(OUTFILE))  
$(foreach var,$(shell cat $(OUTFILE)),$(eval $(var)))  
runcmd -value $(myvar)
```

out file would contain a series of make variable assignments "myvar:=400"
In using the shell function any command line/make variables do not get passed to the tcl shell as environment variables.
If I dereference env(MY_ENV_VAR) from within the tcl shell it does not exist.
If I don't use the shell command the foreach/eval line gets executed before the out file is created but the variables are visible in the tcl shell.
I'm sure there is a more graceful way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that's pretty crazy.

One answer is that you need to export make variables if you want them to be passed to a sub-shell.  So you need something like `$(eval export $(var))`.

However, that might not work because make could have constructed the environment for the subprocesses at the beginning of the rule, and it may not recompute it for each individual recipe line.  I'm not sure.

In general this is a completely bizarre way to go about things, but before I can suggest a more sane alternative I need to understand how much of the infrastructure you have license to modify.  Can you change the `evalVars.tcl` file to generate a different type of output?  Does `OUTFILE` have to be a target-specific variable (possibly different for different targets)?  Or is there only one for the makefile?  Is it required that the `evalVars.tcl` be run in the same recipe, or can they be two different targets with one depending on the other?

By far the most reasonable approach to this is to modify `evalVars.tcl` so it generates shell variable assignments, not make variable assignments.  If you did that you could just do something like:

```
foo:
        ./evalVars.tcl -arg1 $(ARG1) -outFile $(OUTFILE) \
            && . $(OUTFILE) \
            && runcmd -value $$myvar
```

where the contents of `$(OUTFILE)` would be lines like `export myvar=400`

Comment: Thanks for the response. guessed as much :-). I tried the environment variable approach but using .oneshell but i think i ran into some issues and ended up with this. I could use the && combined with the env vars. you could have evalvars in a separate recipe but each target that calls it needs to pass certain arguments to it and use the vars it sets. the output of evalvars can be modified if needed

Comment: I tried out your alternative which worked well till i ran into variables whose values have special characters. i tried grouping these with ' '  escaping etc.
as an example setenv a 'b[c=1]'

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand the problem.  Please provide an example of the types of special values / variable assignments you're having trouble with.

Comment: setenv VARNAME  'span[hosts=1]' a lsf resource string for example.

Comment: I don't understand: that looks like csh syntax.  You can't use csh with make, you need to use POSIX shell (Bourne shell).  And, if you use simply `VARNAME=span[hosts=1]` in POSIX shell it works fine: no quoting required.  No quoting required when you use it in the command line either.